# A special topology compatible with partial orders

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, lattice-orders

**Question.** Are there contradictions with the following topology $\tau$? If not, is it an established topology known with a conventional name? Thanks in advance.

> Suppose $(Y, <)$ is a non-empty complete lattice. That is, every non-empty subset has both a *meet* and a *join*. Equip $Y$ with a topology $\tau$, such that every converging net that is also order-preserving, w.r.t. its index directed set, converges to its join. That is for a directed set $(I, <=')$, if the net $(y_i)_{i\in I}$ converges under topology $\tau$, and satisfies $i_1<='i_2\Rightarrow y_{i_1}<=y_{i_2}$, then $y_i\rightarrow \bigvee y_i$ .

Comment: Yeah, someone has to prove such topology exists. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @freakish Thanks. I'm trying to generalize the Euclidean topology of $\mathbb{R}$ to general posets with some completeness. First I restrict to complete lattices, since it should be easier.

Comment: @freakish perhaps I should focus on the property of "$(r_n)$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ iff $\liminf = \limsup$" property to generalize?